# Enviando string da view para a controller via Ajax. Codeigniter, javascript e php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter, controller

estou tentando enviar uma informação que está no bloco de código javascript para a minha controller, porem não estou sabendo como capturar a informação na minha controller.

Segue código Javascript da view:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   fetch('http://localhost/page.com.br/public/id_notification', {
    method: "POST",
    id: 1515
   })
   .then(function(response) {
    return console.log(response);
   });   

</script>
```

Arquivo de rota:

```
$route['id_notification'] = 'post_notification/insert_id_post_notification';
```

Minha controller:

```js
<?php

class Post_notification extends CI_Controller
{
    public function insert_id_post_notification()
    {
        $teste = $_POST['id'];
        var_dump($teste);
    }
}

?>
```

Nome da minha controller: post_notification.

Quero capturar o id com valor 1515 na minha controller. *Valor de teste*
Desde já muito obrigado pessoal.

Comment: Seu fetch está errado: https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/635&hl=pt-BR dá uma olhada

Comment: Olá amigo! realmente estava incorreto, 
alterei e ficou da seguinte forma

Comment: fetch('http://localhost/app.realizaconstrutora.com.br/public/id_notification', {
    method: "POST",
    body: 1515
   })
   .then(function(response) {
    return console.log(response);
   });

Comment: Agora preciso saber como capturar esse valor 1515 na minha controller :/

Comment: assim: `fetch('localhost/app.realizaconstrutora.com.br/public/id_notification', { method: "POST", body: 'source=1515', headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"} }) .then(function(response) { return console.log(response); });` e depois no seu código se busca pela `source` assim vai funcionar no seu backend...

Answer (score 0):

Passa a url inteira sem a rota dessa  forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                fetch('http://localhost/page.com.br/public/Post_notification/insert_id_post_notification', {
                    method: "POST",
                    id: 1515
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    return console.log(response);
                });         

    </script>
```

Então no seu Controller faça o seguinte

```
<?php

class Post_notification extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
    }
    public function insert_id_post_notification()
    {

        $teste = $this->input->post('id');
        var_dump($teste);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Coloquei e o Ajax está enviando com status Ok, porém, jogando a url do Ajax direto eu consigo acessar o método **insert_id_post_notification**, porém através do ajax não está acessando. Acabei de postar como está meu código atualizado :/

Comment: @FelippeSousa Poderia me Mostrar a resposta do servidor

Comment: Consegui fazer com o axios js, deu certo aqui. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Meu código js na view agora está da seguinte forma:

```js
var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('id', '1515');
            fetch('http://localhost/page.com.br/public/post_notification/insert_id_post_notification', {
                method: "POST",
                body: formData
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                return console.log(response);
            });
```

O POST com o Ajax está com status OK!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha Controller está da seguinte forma:

```html
<?php
    class Post_notification extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        public function insert_id_post_notification()
        {        
            $teste = $this->input->post('id');
            var_dump($teste);
        }
    }
?>
```

Não está chegando no var_dump, então nem está chegando no metodo **insert_id_post_notification** da controller. Não sei o porque, pois jogando o diretorio que estou usando no ajax direto na url eu consigo acessar :/

Answer (score 0):

Código com Axios js funcionou!

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">    axios.post('http://localhost/app.realizaconstrutora.com.br/public/id_notification', {
     id: 1515
    })
    .then((response) => {
     console.log(response.data);
       });
</script>
```

Valeu galera!

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o jQuery para falicitar

```
// CDN : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js
$.post(
       'link',//url de destino
       {id: '151515'},//dados e como vao chegar no controller, para adicionar mais dados basta dar , e continuar o array
       function(data){
    //Aqui voce lida com o retorno do controller
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Man manda manda da seguinte forma:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id', 14);
formData.append('name', 'teste');
formData.append('valor', '1.4');

fetch('http://localhost/page.com.br/public/id_notification', {
                method: "POST",
                body: formData
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                return console.log(response);
            });
```

Comment: Olá, coloquei da seguinte forma: 
`var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id', '1515');
fetch('http://localhost/page.com.br/public/id_notification', {
method: "POST",
body: formData
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                return console.log(response);
            });`

O POST com ajax está enviando com status ok.
A rota esta correta! Jogando ela direto na url eu consigo acessar o método na controller, porém o ajax não está entrando no metodo **insert_id_post_notification** da controller, mesmo com o diretório correto